# Eclipse - Loading Angular CLI Versions Stuck

Tags: eclipse, angular

I'm trying to create a new Angularjs 2 project with my Eclipse IDE (Neon.1), however the setup wizard seems to be stuck at `Loading the list of CLI versions`

[image]

I am behind a corporate proxy but as far as I know it is configured correctly. Is there something I could be missing something here?

**UPDATE**

The following is logged when I open the wizard

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: registry.npmjs.org
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.modernweb.common.core.common.VersionsObtainJob.run(VersionsObtainJob.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `http://registry.npmjs.org` to my Proxy Bypass resolved this issue, so it in fact was my proxy settings